# VlcMediaPlayer integrating in QGraphicsView class

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, libvlc

I need to use the vlc library with Qt. It's work well, but now i want to use the VlcMediaPlayer in a QGraphicsView and it doesn't work. There are no images displayed. Does anyone have an idea ?
This is my code :

```
 VlcWidgetVideo *widgetVideo = new VlcWidgetVideo;
 _instance = new VlcInstance(VlcCommon::args(), this);
 _player = new VlcMediaPlayer(_instance);     
 _player->setVideoWidget(widgetVideo); 

 m_scene = new QGraphicsScene
        m_scene->addWidget(videoWidget);
 setScene(m_scene);
```

[EDIT]

I found how to diplay the player by specifying the parent :

```
VlcWidgetVideo *widgetVideo = new VlcWidgetVideo(this);
```

But now i can't add other items or widgets above my player. I have this warning :

```
QGraphicsProxyWidget::setWidget: cannot embed widget 0x1a5005f0 which is not a toplevel widget, and is not a child of an embedded widget
```

Thanks for paying attention.

Comment: What Qt version do you use?

Comment: New edit : new issue...

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use `QGraphicsScene` instead of `QQuickView`?

Comment: Yes, there is. I need to draw rectangles, and write texts above the video. But i don't know `QQuickView` very well, so maybe it's possible, isn't it ?

Comment: Please look demos at http://webchimera.org (but you will have to install plugin) - it was done with QQuickView and libvlc

Comment: And yes, all it possible with QQuickView and even much more effective than with VlcWidgetVideo.

Comment: hum... thank you very much !! I will study it !

Comment: If finally you will decide try it, you will require this: https://github.com/RSATom/QmlVlc It's libvlc wrapper for QML

Comment: Interresting ! Thank you very much for your help ! I will try with this !